# PHP / mySQL query causing errors with memberpress and wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, memberpress

So... we have memberpress installed and I have come in as new developer.

there is this code below, written by previous developer....

```
    if($user_meta['mepr_is_training_active'][0] != ''  && $user_meta['mepr_is_training_active'][0] == 'on'){
        $have_training = 'yes';
    }
    else{
        $mpca_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'mpca_corporate_account_id', true);
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM wp_mepr_corporate_accounts WHERE id = ".$mpca_id);
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        foreach($results as $result){
            if(!empty($result->user_id) || $result->user_id != '' || $result->user_id != ' '){
                $user_meta_parent = get_user_meta(trim($result->user_id));
                if($user_meta_parent['mepr_is_training_active'][0] != ''  && $user_meta_parent['mepr_is_training_active'][0] == 'on'){
                    $have_training = 'yes';
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
```

Our error logs show the following:

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 for query SELECT user_id FROM wp_mepr_corporate_accounts WHERE id =
```

I do understand most of this, is it the use of quotation marks not being correct?

help much appreciated.

thanks

have attempted to replace quotation marks, cant see the problem.

Comment: Apparently `$mpca_id` is empty. YOu'll need to figure out why you're not getting it from `get_user_meta`

Comment: i think i might know why. a free trial level was added, this is not being handled correctly then, as the template is the same. need if else rules adding for the free trial, that will sort it out i think. would be empty if the login is not a corporate account...

Comment: this is better tho, and PHP8 compatible? $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT user_id FROM wp_mepr_corporate_accounts WHERE id = '.$mpca_id);

Comment: Not quite. Read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ to see how to properly use the prepare function.

Comment: hi, sorry but none of that helps. it doesnt solve the error im seeing. i agree with first comment, i solved that and got back the ID but the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing $wpdb->prepare statement with this one.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM wp_mepr_corporate_accounts WHERE id = %d", $mpca_id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this did it. can I ask, what is the %d doing in the query- i know it is telling it that this is an integer, but is this a requirement for higher versions of mySQL?

Comment: it is a placeholder that can be used in the query string.
You can read more about wpdb::prepare statement on WordPress documentation.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/


if you have solved your issue mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Just a bit more to my feedback, we have a free trial option on the site. this obviously then will return an empty string from the query as this only checks for the corporate account ID. previous developer missed this, obviously... thanks again, you saved my bacon here. this bit I can handle....   ` if($user_meta['mepr_is_training_active'][0] != ''  && $user_meta['mepr_is_training_active'][0] == 'on' || $is_free_trial == 'yes' ){
  $have_training = 'yes';
 } `

Comment: Ask another question with an appropriate title.